# Help required in finding determinant using characteristic equation.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A problem in my textbook proceeds as follows:

Find $\det(A)$ given that $A$ has $p(\lambda)$ as its characteristic polynomial

a) $p(\lambda)=\lambda^3-2\lambda^2+\lambda+5$

b) $p(\lambda)=\lambda^4-\lambda^3+7$

What  I did was:

a) Since $\det(\lambda I-A)=\lambda^3-2\lambda^2+\lambda+5$, then $\det(-A)=5$. Hence, $\det(A)=-5$.
b) Since $\det(\lambda I-A)=\lambda^4-2\lambda^3+7$, then $\det(-A)=7$. Hence, $\det(A)=7$.

Am I correct here?

Comment: Cuidado @Oscar: in general, for a $\;n\times n\;$ matrix, we have that $\;\det(-A)=(-1)^n\implies \det A\;$ , so in (a) the determinant is $\;-5\;$ , for example...

Comment: That is not accurate, @EgoKilla ...

Comment: @Egokilla The determinant in a $\;3\times3\;$ matrix's char. polynomial is not the constant term but **minus** the constant term... unless you define the char. pol. as $\;\det(A-tI)\;$ . Yet the OP, by (a)-(b), seems to be taking $\;\det(tI-A)\;$ ...

Comment: You're right, my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost correct but not quite.

**Hint**.  If
$$A=\pmatrix{1&2\cr 1&1\cr}$$
write down $-A$ and find the determinants of $A$ and $-A$, doing all the working and not attempting to use any short cuts.  Then repeat for
$$A=\pmatrix{1&2&3\cr 1&1&2\cr -1&0&1\cr}\ .$$
What do you notice?

Comment: For the determinant of the 2x2, both were -1. For the 3x3, det(A)=-2 and det(-A)=0. So I'm thinking that for an nxn matrix, when n is an even number det(A)=det(-A) and that is not the case when n is odd.

Comment: You need to do the calculations more carefully for the $3\times3$ example.

Comment: Oh I see where I messed up; the det(A)=det(-A).

Comment: For the $3\times3$ case, $\det(A)\ne\det(-A)$.

Comment: Okay, so I did get that they're different, but I cant seem to connect this to the answer I posted.

Comment: Did you notice *anything* about the answers in the $3\times3$ case, other than that they are different?

Comment: Theyre opposite signs of each other.

Answer (score 2):

In general when the characteristic polynomial is written in simplest form the constant term of the polynomial is equal to ${-1}^n \cdot det(A)$. Where $n$ is the dimension of the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = I$.

Then $\det(\lambda I - A) = \det [(\lambda - 1) I] = (\lambda - 1)^n = \ldots + (-1)^n$, for $A$ being $n\times n$.

By your logic, we'd conclude that $\det (-A) = (-1)^n$.  But it's nonsense to say that.  $A$ is the identity; the determinant of $I$ does not depend on its dimensionality.

Moreover, does it make sense to say that $\det(-I) = \det I$?  I don't think so.

Comment: therefore, it shouldn't be -5, but 5?